# FlutterFire CLI doesn't find installed Firebase CLI

Tags: firebase, flutter

I  encountered a **bug** with **FlutterFire CLI**, and I didn't find any solution. I would love to have your feedback and your help! Don't hesitate to ask any questions for additional context.

### Bug

> macOS Monterey - version 12.3

*FlutterFire CLI* ask me to install *Firebase CLI* even if it is **already installed** and logged in my account.

#### Steps to reproduce

```
>>> firebase --version
10.4.0
>>> firebase login
Already logged in as <my email address>
>>> flutterfire configure
i Found 0 Firebase projects.
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase --version 
ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.
```

#### Expected behavior

I would expect `flutterfire configure` to find *Firebase CLI* and run.

---

### Additional context

```
# ~/.zshrc
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/development/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"

alias firebase="`npm config get prefix`/bin/firebase"
```

---

#### Flutter doctor

Run `flutter doctor` and paste the output below:

```
>>> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on macOS 12.3 21E230 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.65.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

---

#### Flutter dependencies

Run `flutter pub deps -- --style=compact` and paste the output below:

```
>>> flutter pub deps -- --style=compact
Dart SDK 2.16.1
Flutter SDK 2.10.3
awachat 1.0.0+8

dependencies:
- cupertino_icons 1.0.4
- firebase_core 1.13.1 [firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_core_web flutter meta]
- firebase_messaging 11.2.11 [firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_messaging_platform_interface firebase_messaging_web flutter meta]
- flutter 0.0.0 [characters collection material_color_utilities meta typed_data vector_math sky_engine]
- flutter_chat_ui 1.5.5 [flutter diffutil_dart equatable flutter_chat_types flutter_link_previewer intl meta photo_view]
- http 0.13.4 [async http_parser meta path]
- uuid 3.0.6 [crypto]
- web_socket_channel 2.1.0 [async crypto stream_channel]

dev dependencies:
- change_app_package_name 1.0.0
- flutter_launcher_icons 0.9.2 [args image path yaml]
- flutter_lints 1.0.4 [lints]
- flutter_test 0.0.0 [flutter test_api path fake_async clock stack_trace vector_math async boolean_selector characters charcode collection matcher material_color_utilities meta source_span stream_channel string_scanner term_glyph typed_data]

transitive dependencies:
- archive 3.2.2 [crypto path]
- args 2.3.0
- async 2.8.2 [collection meta]
- boolean_selector 2.1.0 [source_span string_scanner]
- characters 1.2.0
- charcode 1.3.1
- clock 1.1.0
- collection 1.15.0
- crypto 3.0.1 [collection typed_data]
- csslib 0.17.1 [source_span]
- diffutil_dart 3.0.0
- equatable 2.0.3 [collection meta]
- fake_async 1.2.0 [clock collection]
- firebase_core_platform_interface 4.2.5 [collection flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_core_web 1.6.1 [firebase_core_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins js meta]
- firebase_messaging_platform_interface 3.2.1 [firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_messaging_web 2.2.9 [firebase_core firebase_core_web firebase_messaging_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins js meta]
- flutter_chat_types 3.3.1 [equatable json_annotation meta]
- flutter_link_previewer 2.6.3 [flutter flutter_chat_types flutter_linkify html http linkify meta url_launcher]
- flutter_linkify 5.0.2 [flutter linkify]
- flutter_web_plugins 0.0.0 [flutter js characters collection material_color_utilities meta typed_data vector_math]
- html 0.15.0 [csslib source_span]
- http_parser 4.0.0 [charcode collection source_span string_scanner typed_data]
- image 3.1.3 [archive meta xml]
- intl 0.17.0 [clock path]
- js 0.6.3
- json_annotation 4.4.0 [meta]
- linkify 4.1.0
- lints 1.0.1
- matcher 0.12.11 [stack_trace]
- material_color_utilities 0.1.3
- meta 1.7.0
- path 1.8.0
- petitparser 4.4.0 [meta]
- photo_view 0.13.0 [flutter]
- plugin_platform_interface 2.1.2 [meta]
- sky_engine 0.0.99
- source_span 1.8.1 [collection path term_glyph]
- stack_trace 1.10.0 [path]
- stream_channel 2.1.0 [async]
- string_scanner 1.1.0 [charcode source_span]
- term_glyph 1.2.0
- test_api 0.4.8 [async boolean_selector collection meta source_span stack_trace stream_channel string_scanner term_glyph matcher]
- typed_data 1.3.0 [collection]
- url_launcher 6.0.20 [flutter url_launcher_android url_launcher_ios url_launcher_linux url_launcher_macos url_launcher_platform_interface url_launcher_web url_launcher_windows]
- url_launcher_android 6.0.15 [flutter url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_ios 6.0.15 [flutter url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_linux 3.0.0 [flutter url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_macos 3.0.0 [flutter url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_platform_interface 2.0.5 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_web 2.0.9 [flutter flutter_web_plugins url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_windows 3.0.0 [flutter url_launcher_platform_interface]
- vector_math 2.1.1
- xml 5.3.1 [collection meta petitparser]
- yaml 3.1.0 [collection source_span string_scanner]
```

---